# How to set the BackImage of a ChartArea at run time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, mschart

Anyone know why the ChartArea.BackImage is a property of type string?
Would it not have made more sense for this to have been a property of type Image?

Or to put it another way, how can I set the background image of a ChartArea to an image generated at run-time (e.g. from GraphicPath objects)?

Suggestions are welcome, thanks.

Comment: What sort of control are you using? (Some kind of graph control, I assume, but you need to clarify.) And which UI framework (WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, ASP.NET)?

Comment: It is a control that's already in the toolbox (VS2010 under Data).  The namespace is: System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting - but I also noticed that System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting also has a similar set of classes and properties.

Comment: Use NamedImage! See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution using NamedImage

```
var chartBackImage = new Bitmap(1,1); //some bmp
chart1.Images.Add(new NamedImage("GiveSomeName", chartBackImage));
chart1.Areas[0].BackImage = Images[0].Name;
chart1.Areas[0].BackImageWrapMode = ChartImageWrapMode.Scaled; //extra
```

Answer (score 6):

As MSDN states here: [ChartArea.BackImage Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chartarea.backimage.aspx). The BackImage property is a string value that represents the URL of an image file.

So to provide an image created dynamically you will need to create your image (checkout the following article about using objects from the System.Drawing namespace to achieve this): [Dynamic Image Generation with ASP.Net](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jrule/archive/2004/08/16/215393.aspx)

Which you can either:

1 - Store to the file system.

Or

2 -  Setup an HttpHandler to serve it dynamically.

See: [Using HttpHandlers to serve image files](http://blog.kurtschindler.net/post/using-httphandlers-to-serve-image-files)

Either way you would need to set the path to the image like so:

```
Chart.ChartAreas[0].BackImage = imagePath;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I prefer NamedImage. I add a sample in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Also set the chart and chartarea BackColor = "Transparent" for the image to show

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" BackColor="Transparent" >
    <Titles>
        <asp:Title Text="Bubble Chart"></asp:Title>
    </Titles>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" BackColor="Transparent"></asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
    <Legends>
        <asp:Legend LegendStyle="Table" Docking="Bottom" IsDockedInsideChartArea="false" Name="Legend1"></asp:Legend>
    </Legends>
</asp:Chart>
```